# Values of array grouped in single variable in created element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have made a function in jquery in which i want to get the set of array to be printed in created element. The set of array are grouped in a single variable from where these should be extracted and printed one by one in the created element on click of a button again and again. But in my function the sets are extracted but printing on replacing the previous set by clicking the button again and again. Kindly help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    myfunction1();
    });

a=0;
    function myfunction1() {
    var i = 0;
    var cars = [["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"], ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"],    ["Petrol", "Diesel", "CNG"]];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");
 
 
  div.append(p1, p2, p3); // To append multiple created elements in the created parent element.
  if ( a < cars.length) { // To run index upto arrays length. a variable stands for index no.
  $("body").append(div);  
    } 
    var x = div.querySelectorAll("div > p"); // We are using div.querySelectorAll("div > p") because we are fetching created elements p from created element div. We should not use document.querySelectorAll("div > p") because we are not fetching div element and its p elements from document or body.
    $("div > p").each(function() {
    
                $(this).text(cars[a][i]);
            i++;        
                });
  a++;
    }
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="demo">This is a heading</h2>

<h1 id="demo1">This is a paragraph.</h1>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It'll be easier to show what the expected html code should looks like

Comment: a fast solution `$("div:last > p").each(......`